# Can anyone explain why this happens "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" sccm powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have this little snippet from my script that is throwing " Object reference not set to an instance of an object", however if I close powershell then open it and connect to the SCCM it will allow me to run the one liner manually.

The aim is to pass it a list and go through, grabbing the application name from the install ID and out putting it to a text file. It has worked once previously but then not again.

```
$list = Get-ChildItem $directory | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select name, LastWriteTime
$selection = $list | Out-GridView -Title "Choose application" -PassThru
$selection = $selection.name
$collectionids = Get-Content -Path "$directory\$selection"
$version = Get-Date -Format "dd_MM_yyyy_HHmmss"

foreach ($i in $collectionids){Write-Host "$i listed"
try{
    $installcollectionname = Get-CMApplicationDeployment -CollectionId $i | select ApplicationName -ExpandProperty ApplicationName
    Write-Host "Found $installcollectionname Adding to document" -ForegroundColor Green
    $installcollectionname | Out-File -filePath "$textfiles\Application_names_$version.txt" -Force -Append 
    }catch{
            Write-Host "Unable to find $i" -ForegroundColor red
            $i | Out-File -filepath "$logpath\failed.txt" -Append -Force
          }

                             }
```

Out put from running manually:

```
PS ONE:\> $i
ONE001F6

PS ONE:\> Get-CMApplicationDeployment -CollectionId $i | select ApplicationName -ExpandProperty ApplicationName
Get-CMApplicationDeployment : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CMApplicationDeployment -CollectionId $i | select ApplicationName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CMApplicationDeployment], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Deployments.Commands.GetApplicationDeploymentCommand
```

Comment: Are you sure your `$collectionids` doesn't contain empty values from reading blank lines in the file? Make sure all elements have a value by appending `| Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}` at the end of the `Get-Content` line

Comment: thanks for your answer theo, it turns out it was a false positive on the site. 
I was also using $i in two seprate areas of script and that was also messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out even though it was "connected" it wasn't actually connected to SCCM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).